How to append Unicode character to content of user-editable element (span) for sites like Reddit?
I'm trying to write a simple Chrome extension that will listen for a particular keystroke combination (say Alt-Shift-0) and append a particular Unicode character (e.g. Œ) to the user-entered text in a rich-text editing element like the one Reddit uses. After hours of searching and trying different approaches, nothing works.
Here is the relevant code in my extension (located in a content script):
$(document).keydown(function(event) {  
  if (event.which == 48  && event.altKey && event.shiftKey) {
    insertTextAtCursor("Œ");
    return false;
  }
});

function insertTextAtCursor(txt) {
  var txtae = $(document.activeElement);
  var caretPos = txtae[0].selectionStart;
  var textAreaTxt = txtae.val();
  var txtToAdd = txt;
  txtae.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos));
}

The extension loads without error and my "keydown" event handler runs as expected whenever a key is pressed. But the insertTextAtCursor function does not insert any text into any <span> elements where user text input is typed on Reddit. It's like the val() function does nothing at all. Is there a better approach I should take in this case?
Here is the HTML code from Reddit showing the <span> where user text input goes:
<div slot="rte" name="body" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" class="px-md py-sm outline-none relative resize-y overflow-y-auto min-h-[44px] leading-5 box-border" tabindex="1" aria-placeholder="Add a comment" data-lexical-editor="true" style="user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; --emote-size: 20px; --emote-scale: 0.15625; --emote-line-height: inherit;">
  <p class="first:mt-0 last:mb-0" dir="ltr">
    <span data-lexical-text="true">HERE IS WHERE USER-TYPED TEXT APPEARS</span>
  </p>
</div>


Try dispatching a change event or use the deprecated document.execCommand, example.

Thank you!!! That worked like a charm! document.execCommand is exactly what I needed.
